# 401 Authentication error in HTTPClient

Tags: android, ioexception, http-status-code-401, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm developing Android application using HTTPClient.

My server returns 401 response code together with some useful response data.
Android HTTPClient throws IOException and does not extract the data.

Is there a possibility to receive the response data using HTTPClient?
If not, what are the best practices to extract the data after 401 response in Android?

Answer (score 0):

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
            String result = null;
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            try {
                result = httpClient.execute(httpget, responseHandler); // this result will have the response received from server
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Toast the response received
```

Comment: Hi Bhavit, thanks for the quick reply. I don't see where you define the response

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it soon. Anyhow - this doesn't seems as a working answer, since result will be null if exception is thrown - won't it? Do you think I can get anything out of responseHandler in that case?

Comment: No, u will not get any response from the server then. In that case, you can assign result = "Exeption thrown" in the catch block.

Comment: If so, the answer for the first question is "no". Do you know a way to get a response in this case?

Comment: If there is an exception in your client code, then there is no possibility of connecting to server and getting response. There is no way for for achieving this,  as much I know.